# Is there a model of set theory with choice but without a universal well-order?

Tags: set-theory

By "universal well-order", I mean a class-function that bijects $V$ with $ORD^V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

It is not hard to prove that a universal well order exists if and only if $V=\rm HOD$. If you may allow a parameter then you can get away with $\mathrm{HOD}[x]$ for some set $x$.

However as shown by Joel Hankins in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/110823/7206) , it is consistent not to have even a global linear order. The idea is to use class forcing and add a proper class of new sets, and to do it in a way that no set can give you a global linear ordering.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had in mind with parameters. I do see that equivalence, but also saw that any forcing extension of a model with a universal well-order still has a universal well-order. I guess a counter example thus requires class forcing.

Comment: Yes, that is true.